How to hot switch SwiftData model container?
I want to add switching SwiftData's work modes between local and iCloud. It's the basic cloud sync on/off logic.
I created a draft logic to do this:
@Observable
final class DataStore {
    
    private(set) var container: ModelContainer
    private(set) var lastUpdate: Date = .now
    private(set) var iCloud: Bool
    
    init() {
        let iCloud = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "storage.key.icloud.enabled")
        container = Self.container(iCloud: iCloud)
        self.iCloud = iCloud
    }
    
    func toggle(_ value: Bool) {
        let iCloud = value
        UserDefaults.standard.set(iCloud, forKey: "storage.key.icloud.enabled")
        
        self.container = Self.container(iCloud: iCloud)
        lastUpdate = .now
        self.iCloud = iCloud
    }
    
    private static func container(iCloud: Bool) -> ModelContainer {
        let schema = Schema([
            Model.self,
        ])
          
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false, cloudKitDatabase: iCloud ? .private("iCloud.test.3") : .none)
        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}


But when I toggle it, I get a query crash. I can't find any related info. Can you describe the toggle logic to me step by step?

iCloud is used to synch data between devices and it’s something you either have active all the time or not at all. So you can not use it the way you want to to at all, switching between storing data locally or externally. You always store data locally with SwiftData (and Core Data)

I’m voting to close this question because it’s not relevant and based on a misunderstanding of the functionality
